# How do I properly protect a password when the source code is available?

Tags: javascript, security, hash, passwords, password-protection

I am building a web application that has a user login feature that I want to make as secure as I can. When a new user is created, I use this javascript function to hash the user's information and eventually store the output in a mySQL database :

```
function hash(user) {

    var part1 = mix(user.username, user.password);
    var part2 = mix(user.random_value + salt, user.password);

    return mix(part1, part2);

    function mix(part1, part2) {

        var hash = sha3_256(part1 + part2);

        var rehash = 10000;
        while(rehash--) {
            hash = sha3_256(hash + salt + rehash);
        }
        return hash;
    }

}
```

the database contains the username, the random value and the hash function's output, whereas the salt variable is a random string that is declared outside the function and never changes.

As far as I could gather through reading some previous posts about password security, this is a decently safe way of doing things (although I would appreciate any suggestions), but here is my concern :

If I suppose someone could gain access to the database and get all the information stored for a certain user and given that he can see exactly how the hash function operates (since this code is visible in the browser and on GitHub). Couldn't this malicious person just run all possible combinations of 8 characters (minimum password length) through my function and see what value of password creates the correct hash ?

This surely would take some time, but it is not impossible to run through all possibilities eventually and therefore get access to the account.

Is there any way to protect against this kind of attack ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Side note: I assume you are doing this server-side (nodejs?).  Your implementation is non-standard and your terminology is mixed up (the normal terminology has "salt" as a value that changes every time, whereas "pepper" is a fixed server side string), but it does have the main concepts in place.  I'd recommend though that you would use a standard "password hashing" algorithm such as scrypt or bcrypt.

In regard to your question "*Couldn't this malicious person just run all possible combinations of 8 characters (minimum password length) through my function and see what value of password creates the correct hash ?*", the answer is yes, but it's going to take him a long time to do that.  That's the entire purpose of your `rehash` variable: to slow the user down.  See: [Our password hashing has no clothes](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/) for more details.

Comment: this is just regular javascript and not server side, is that a bad idea ?

Comment: @pabombs: yeah, if you are only doing client side processing and server is just accepting what the client sends it, then it is vulnerable to pass-the-hash attacks, but here I am making assumptions about your implementation.  You might have a glance through this link, provided that it is not too academic: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf

Comment: I am using part1 and part2 to check that its actually the user, and not just the hash from the databse. Both parts are created when a user logs in so it can be checked later.

Comment: @pabombs, so far you have only specified what the client does.  If you want a complete analysis, we need to know what the server is doing.  But generally I warn that you seem to be trying to roll your own solution, which is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: as it stands, the server side code's only use is interacting with the database. I am starting to feel like my solution is not appropriate, could you point me to a more established way of doing things ?

Comment: @pabombs, yeah sounds flawed in my judgment. Good sources are: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm and https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016 .  Both are targeted at developers.

Comment: using bscrypt is so much simpler than what I was doing, I'm not sure why I didn't use it from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Your threat model is "attacker gets complete read access to database contents", yes?

Solutions are:

1. Don't let that happen
2. Segregate the web servers from the database servers, and use Peppering

This involves storing a secret on the web server (never on the database server). Use this to HMAC the password first. Then hash it for storage.

If the database server gets compromised, the passwords cannot be easily cracked. This even works if attacker can do SQL injections, but can't otherwise get web server info

Notes:

1. Don't use SHA{anything} for password hashing. Only use bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2
2. Do not roll your own security system. Use existing frameworks
3. Your system should be secure even if it's open source. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle
4. Run HIDS on your web and db servers and NIDS on your network so you can (hopefully) detect a breach and notify your users so they can change their passwords on other sites

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a sufficiently good hashing algorithm, it doesn't matter. That is because (*emphasis mine*)

> A cryptographic hash function is a mathematical algorithm that maps data of arbitrary size to a bit string of a fixed size (a hash function) which is designed to also be **one-way function**, that is, a function which is **infeasible to invert**.

Cryptographic Hashes are designed to be open source, and the point of using them over clear text password storage is so that if data is breached, the root passwords are not reversible. [Wiki on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification)

Now if you have rolled your own, or are trying to prevent someone from knowing you are using a weak hashing algorithm, you are in trouble.

Also, your salts / pepper, should live only in the instantiation of the application. You certainly can load it up to github, but I would recommend changing that configuration in your live application.

To address your concern about running through every 8 character password, that is just a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) concern. Which is why using *hunter2* is a bad password. Your salt/peppering helps mitigate that but in general, guessing is infeasible. [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18175) is a good explination of the timing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't this malicious person just run all possible combinations of 8 characters (minimum password length) through my function and see what value of password creates the correct hash?

Absolutely. *The goal of a good password hash is to slow how long it takes for an adversary to generate each hash*, especially as what might be “slow” on a traditional CPU is fast on a GPU (or many; think of a crypto mining farm) or an ASIC.

This is why password-hashing algorithms such as bcrypt, scrypt, and Argon were designed. (The function shown in the question is more akin to PBKDF2 which is *not memory-hard*.)

Thus, [ignoring a attempt to rely solely on an additional secret stored/managed outside the code](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#peppering) (eg. PKI private key or “pepper”), the two general options are to:

- Make the hash function slower for the adversary.

  See one of the above mentioned password hash functions, which provide varying levels of hardness on GPUs/ASICs;
- Help users choose *longer passphrases with more key entropy*. This has the implied goal that such “passwords” are not found in common password dictionaries.

  In addition to user education (eg. clear messaging), a trivial method
  to help is to require a “password” to be at least 12/14 characters *and* drop some of the traditional restrictions. As
  the input space is increased, even a fast brute-force approach
  becomes less attractive. See [obligatory
  link](https://xkcd.com/936/).

---

*Since the original home-spun function shown has **no inherent advantage to PBKDF2**, and a disadvantage of not being a scrutinized algorithm, I recommend using PBKDF2 with an appropriate salt/output size and iteration count.*

One can also trivially support a “pepper” with a KDF (including PBKF2 with one round) feeding the actual iteration hash.